# What is the nil/zero value of bson.ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, objectid

I was creating unary tests when I got stuck on the following situation:

- I have an object that has a foreign key. For some reason, I need to switch the ID and it works. However, sometimes, I need to remove this ID. If I have an ID, I realise a certain action and if I don't, then nothing happens.

However, I can't find the way to set my `bson.ObjectId` as `nil` or zero.

Does anyone knows how to do or a work around?

Comment: This is like &string("Hello"). It's invalid.

But you can store the `bson.ObjectIdHex(id)` value to some `tmp` variable and then assign `&tmp`  it to the `*bson.ObjectID` variable.

Comment: Maybe there is a better way to implement it, but I would have to see the code snippet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Or you can use the [primitive.NilObjectID](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#ObjectID)

> NilObjectID is the zero value for ObjectID.

Comment: I switch the answer from my response to yours, i feel that your approach is more logic :)

Answer (score 2):

bson.ObjectId is an alias for string , therefore the zero value is an empty string ""

Answer (score 2):

Based on @dom answer (in the comments), there is the workaround I am now using:

```
package your_package

import "github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson"

func GenerateNewGuidHelper() *bson.ObjectId {
    id := bson.NewObjectId()
    return &id
}

func IsStringIdValid(id string) bool {
    return id != "" && bson.IsObjectIdHex(id)
}

func ConvertStringIdToObjectId(id string) *bson.ObjectId {
    if id != "" && bson.IsObjectIdHex(id){
        bsonObjectId := bson.ObjectIdHex(id)
        return &bsonObjectId
    }
    return nil
}

func ConvertStringIdsToObjectIds(ids []string) []*bson.ObjectId {
    var _ids []*bson.ObjectId
    for _, id := range ids {
        _ids = append(_ids, ConvertStringIdToObjectId(id))
    }
    return _ids
}

func IsObjectIdValid(id *bson.ObjectId) bool {
    return id.Hex() != "" && bson.IsObjectIdHex(id.Hex())
}

func ConvertObjectIdToStringId(id *bson.ObjectId) string  {
    if id != nil {
        return id.Hex()
    }
    return ""
}

func ConvertObjectIdsToStringIds(ids []*bson.ObjectId) []string {
    var _ids []string
    for _, id := range ids {
        _ids = append(_ids, ConvertObjectIdToStringId(id))
    }
    return _ids
}
```

Also, as said @dom, I am now saving my mongoDB ID as `*bson.ObjectId` instead of `bson.ObjectId`. Example:

```
package datamodels

import (
    "github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson"
)

type User struct {
    ID *bson.ObjectId `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id,proto3" json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
}
```

I hope it helps !